# Evaluate $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{\cos(bx)}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I would like to show that

$$\text{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{\cos(bx)}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{sech}(b)$$

using complex analysis. $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a \neq b$.

Please give some hints.

Comment: I would use the fact that cosine is the real part of the exponential function, then you would have a complex part, and with the inverse polynomial, use its roots to split it, that are complex, so you would have a more comfortable integral to work with.

Comment: Then, check out the exponential integral in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Comment: First I would explain what to do with the poles in the integrand (where the denominator is zero).  At least when $a=b$ the zeros all cancel, but surely your answer is wrong in that case.

Comment: @GEdgar: You are right. The answer is wrong for $a=b$.

Comment: It is annoying that the suggested formula fails for $a=b$, no? Also, note that for $a\ne b$ the integral is undefined. Are you sure this is the formula you were given?

Comment: Should this be understood as Cauchy principal value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the question asking for cannot be right!

At least for $0 < a < b$, we have:

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{PV} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos a x}{\cos b x} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}&= \frac12 \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos a x}{\cos b x}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}
\\&= \frac12 \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+} \Re\left[\int_{-\infty+i\epsilon}^{\infty+i\epsilon} \frac{\cos a z}{\cos b z}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}\right]\tag{*}
\end{align}$$
The last equality is true because at the poles $\pm \frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2 b}, k = 1, 2,\ldots$ of the integrand $\frac{\cos a z}{\cos b z}\frac{1}{1+z^2}$, the residues are all real. Their contribution to the integral is $-\pi i$ times the residues and hence is imaginary.

We can evaluate the integral $(*)$ by completing the contour in upper half plane.

Notice when the $y$ in $z = x + iy$ becomes big, 
$\frac{\cos a z}{\cos b z} \sim e^{-(b-a)(y - ix)} \to 0$.
The upper half circle at infinity contributes nothing to the contour integral and we have:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{-\infty+i\epsilon}^{\infty+i\epsilon} \frac{\cos a z}{\cos b z}\frac{dz}{1+z^2} 
= 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}( \frac{\cos a z}{\cos b z}\frac{1}{1+z^2}; z = i )
= 2 \pi i \frac{\cos a i}{\cos b i}\frac{1}{2i} = \pi \frac{\cosh a}{\cosh b}$$

From this, we get:

$$\operatorname{PV} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos a x}{\cos b x} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cosh a}{\cosh b}$$

This is not what the OP asking to show...

Comment: Your result is a lot more plausible.

Comment: +1, for the same reason as Ron Gordon. I also obtained the same conclusion, but your technique $(*)$ is much more appealing!

Comment: Could you explain how you define PV of this integral and why this coincides with the limit (*)? You seem to be using an idiosyncratic definition of principal value, but maybe it is equivalent to the usual one and at the moment I fail to see the equivalence.

Comment: @Did, $$PV \int_{\mathbb{R}} = \lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2b} - \delta,\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2b} + \delta)}$$ i.e. the PV is the $\delta \to 0$ limit of the integral where points within a distance $\delta$ from the poles are excluded. The contour appear in $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{-\infty+i\epsilon}^{\infty+i\epsilon}$ can be deformed to this plus a bunch of half circles of radius $\delta$ running clockwisely around the poles.

Comment: There seems to be a double limit here, when $\epsilon\to0^+$ and when $R\to+\infty$, of the integral from $-R+i\epsilon$ to $+R+i\epsilon$ but I guess that one can show the limit $R\to+\infty$ does not trouble things.

Comment: @Did, the $\epsilon \to 0+$ here isn't a real limit. It is just a way to specify when one integral along the real axis, how to walk around the pole.

Comment: Not sure I agree. To apply residues one needs a closed curve hence the sum of the contributions of the half-circles around the poles must disappear in the limit (and limit $\epsilon\to0^+$ there is, definitely).

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to **explain what you want**.  Take this one
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\cos(2x)}\;\frac{dx}{1+x^2}
$$
The first spot where it is improper is $x=\pi/4$, and
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\cos x}{\cos(2x)}\;\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = +\infty .
$$
So unless you provide some explanation, your request is impossible.

Comment: The OP added PV in front of the integral.

Comment: And I do not know what PV means with multiple singularities.  He still needs to explain.

Comment: Me neither actually...I was just trying to give this question a chance. Maybe with contour integration.